# How to serializes access to broken async swift APIs that fail when called concurrently?

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, concurrency

Apple's [`generateAssertion(_:clientDataHash:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/dcappattestservice/3573912-generateassertion) is broken and fail majority of concurrent calls with [`invalidKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/dcerror/code/invalidkey) error.  This test will fail 99% of times. If instead the calls are made one after the other then all of them succeed.

```
func testConcurrentGenerateAssertionIsUnsafe() async throws {
    let service = DCAppAttestService.shared
    let attestationKey = try await service.generateKey()
    try await service.attestKey(attestationKey, clientDataHash: Data(SHA256.hash(data: Data())))
    
    let calls = 5
    let concurrentAssertResults = try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Data.self) { taskGroup -> [Data] in
        for i in 1...calls {
            taskGroup.addTask {
                do {
                    let result = try await service.generateAssertion(attestationKey, clientDataHash: Data())
                    print("Assertion result \(i) \(result)")
                    return result
                } catch {
                    print("Throwing error \(i) \(error)")
                    throw error
                }
            }
        }
        var assertResult = [Data]()
        for try await fetchKeyResult in taskGroup { assertResult.append(fetchKeyResult) }
        return assertResult
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Throwing error 5 Error Domain=com.apple.devicecheck.error Code=3 "(null)"
Assertion result 4 140 bytes
Assertion result 3 142 bytes
Throwing error 1 Error Domain=com.apple.devicecheck.error Code=3 "(null)"
Throwing error 2 Error Domain=com.apple.devicecheck.error Code=3 "(null)"
```

For APIs like this it would almost be better if the API could be forced to be synchronous.  I have a solution in place currently to fix this that throws concurrent calls in an array and drains them one by one after waiting on each result and passing it to corresponding completion handler. But is there a better way to deal with this issue?

Comment: Does the completion-handler based variant works?

Comment: No it has the same issue

Comment: It certainly may be a bug, but you should not be generating an assertion for every transaction, unless every transaction is a high value one. Typically you assert your app only when performing high value/premium transactions or on startup with your server returning some kind of session value that you can pass in a header on subsequent transactions

Comment: Right, but still sometimes the code gets called concurrently which leads to `generateAsseration` being called concurrently.

Comment: Maybe you could try to serialize the calls through an actor, could you try this?

Comment: Only using an actor does not help because when one call suspends the other is allowed to run. I have a actor wrapper that puts individual `generateAssertation` calls in an array along with its completion handler. And then executes it one by one. But was wondering if there was a better more standard approach to deal with this issue.